# Find and prove greatest lower bound and least upper bound for set $A=\left\{\frac{4+x}{x} | x \geqslant 1\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

> For any $\varepsilon>0,$ find a number in A that is greater than $(\mathrm{l.u.b.} \; A)-\varepsilon$ and a number in A that is less than $(\mathrm{g.l.b.}\; A)+\varepsilon$ for the set
>    $$A=\left\{\frac{4+x}{x} | x \geqslant 1\right\}$$

I have no problem finding what the lub and glb are, however proving that they are using $\epsilon$ is what has escaped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A=\{\frac{4}{x}+1: x \geq 1\}$

So $\inf A=1$

Indeed assume that exists $s>0$ such that $\frac{4}{x}+1 \geq 1+s, \forall x \geq 1$

Then we would have that $x \leq \frac{4}{s},\forall x \geq 1$ which is a contradiction.

So for every $s>0$ exists $x \geq 1$ such that $\frac{4}{x}+1<1+s$ proving that

$\inf A=1$